# Send a link in mail in MVC

Tags: .net, email, smtpclient

I want to send a link like this [here](http://google.com)  using email  but i am unable to do this. i tried following code.

```
String body = "<a href=\"google.com\">Here</a>";
                var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
                {
                    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("abc@gmail.com", "password"),
                    EnableSsl = true
                };

                client.Send("abc@gmail.com", emailAddress, "Password Recovery", body);
```

But in email i get this.

```
<a href="google.com"> Here </a>
```

Instead of this
      [Here](http://google.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify that body is Html. Like this:

```
    String body = "<a href=\"google.com\">Here</a>";
    var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    {
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential("abc@gmail.com", "password"),
        EnableSsl = true
    };

    MailMessage message = new MailMessage("abc@gmail.com", emailAddress, "Password Recovery",body )
    message.IsBodyHtml = true;

    client.Send(message);
```

Also, it's not MVC question at all...

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `MailMessage` with `IsBodyHtml = true`, then send it via `SmtpClient`

Comment: This answer looks incomplete. It would be better if you put a full code sample which explain more the relationship between your statements.

Comment: Hopefully readers can figure out how to apply this answer, but I agree with @ruffp: don't assume so, and provide an example that ties together your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell that it is **Html**, you can use [MailMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to do it:

```
 MailMessage msg = null;
 var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)

 try
 {
    msg = new MailMessage("from@gmail.com",
                          "to@gmail.com", 
                          "Subject",
                          "Message");
    msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
    client.Send(msg);

 }
```

This [article (Send Html Formatted Emails in asp.net using C#)](http://latest-tutorial.pakifreelancer.com/2013/06/10/send-html-formatted-emails-in-asp-net-using-c/) will also help you.